# NGINX redirect http to https (problem reducing first-byte-time)

Tags: performance, nginx, https, dns, webpagetest

I'm trying to reduce the first byte time (as suggested on Webpagestes https://www.webpagetest.org/result/201202_DiP2_982dc037a5d98317f825d72cba0910a9/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1)

does anyone know why the http call takes so long? And why it has been called if I access the website directly with https?

I tried to reduce the file-size of almost all the project but it seems not to be increasing the performance.

[image]

Comment: Try adding [HSTS](https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/) headers to nginx response.

Comment: Thanks @IvanShatsky it works perfectly. HSTS was configured on NGINX but I didn't include "always" as parameter (as specified in your link).